# Как сделать цикл по textResp.indexOf с несколькими параметрами?

Tags: google-apps-script

Извлекаю  информацию по нескольким  url

Сама [таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LkcJDmiDSrBj2OEuu7siVrpxAbn29VJhZCh-np7AOZY/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: http://joxi.ru/gmvRWYnhL6j8wm]
поля таблицы
url для извлечения
Start1 начало
Startset1 смещение (или длинна Start1)
Start2 новый    поиск от Strt1
StartSet2 смещение для Strt2
End-конец для извлечения
EndSet-смещение для End
Result -результат

Прочитал в [справке](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#cacheService), что правильно работать со всем массивом сразу и не использовать setValue для каждого результата функции, но повторить для своего примера не получилось. 
Вопрос , как правильно сделать такой цикл по всему массиву A1:H и поместить результат функции в Result ?

Сейчас у меня код для первой строки A2:I работает нормально.

```
    function getConten(){
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var url= sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
      getPageContent(url);
    }

    function getPageContent( url) {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var range = sheet.getRange("A1:L");
      var cell = range.getCell(2,9);


      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); 
      var textResp  = response.getContentText();

     var start1= sheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
     var startset1=sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
     var start2=sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
     var startset2=sheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
     var endd=sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
     var endset=sheet.getRange("H2").getValue();



      var start, end, Result

      start= textResp.indexOf(start1,end)+startset1;
      start= textResp.indexOf(start2,start)+startset2;
      end=textResp.indexOf(endd,start)+endset;

       Result= textResp.substring(start, end);
      cell.setValue(Result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getConten2(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var arrData = sheet.getRange("A2:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()

  var arrAnswers = getAllAnswers_(arrData)

  sheet.getRange(2, 9, arrAnswers.length, 1).setValues(arrAnswers)
}

function getAllAnswers_(arrData){
  var arrAnswers = []

  arrData.forEach(function(v,i,a){
    arrAnswers.push([getPageContent2_(v)])
  })

  return arrAnswers
}

function getPageContent2_(arrData) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(arrData[1]); 
  var textResp  = response.getContentText();

  var start, end

  start= textResp.indexOf(arrData[2],end)+arrData[3];
  start= textResp.indexOf(arrData[4],start)+arrData[5];
  end=textResp.indexOf(arrData[6],start)+arrData[7];

  return textResp.substring(start, end);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас именно то что требовалось!

Comment: Сергей, чисто практический вопрос. Почему вы берете такую синтаксически некрасивую`var arrData = sheet.getRange("A2:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()` конструкцию, вместо `getDataRange()` ? Разницы в скорости не будет.

Comment: Потому что, насколько я знаю, getDataRange() возьмет диапазон с 1 строки - а я хотел, чтобы не писать доп условие - со второй

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в этом случае можно было просто в `forEach() `Добавить условие - `if(i=0) return`

Comment: @СергейПряничкин, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift ?

Comment: Можно и так....